# Ember linkTo route with wildcard

Tags: routes, ember.js

I have a route defined as

```
this.route('page', {path: ':site_id/*url'})
```

How can I link to this route? This did not work

```
{{#linkTo 'page' site url=page.url}} // --> ignores the parameter
{{#linkTo 'page' site page.url}} // --> throws error (missing dynamic segment)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query strings are yet still not supported in ember without hooking into the `model` and `serialize` function of a route and doing it by hand, which is not a trivial task.

But there are some workarounds like this one: https://github.com/alexspeller/ember-query, you find it maybe usefull.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hooking into serialize and model is quite easy and it worked. Thanks for the tip